# Date.prototype.toLocaleString() returns incorrect format string

Tags: datetime

```
var endDay = new Date("Sun Jan 01 2017 15:11:45 GMT+0530 (IST)");
endDay = endDay.toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone:"Europe/Oslo" });
console.log(endDay);
```

i got in console : 1 January 2017 at 15:11:45 GMT+5:30

Why resulting string contains "at" word, when i again convert this string to new date returns "Invalid Date" because of "at" in local string.

I executed this on Samsung Tizen TV app.

Please help us in this.

Let me know if you need any further information. Any help regarding this will be much appreciated.

Comment: toLocaleString nomally returns Date in MM/DD/YYYY format. If removing 'at' converts your string back to the Date string, you can try taking out two substrings from **endDay** using `substr(start, end);` and concatenating again.

i.e. First substring will be returned by `endDay.substr(0,16);` .

Comment: I did same thing on overriding Date.prototype.toLocaleString()  prototype method.